# Odoo action view with domain by user's company in xml

Tags: xml, odoo

I am developing an Odoo application and I want to set my action's domain to user's company in XML.

Here is my code:

```
<record id="action_account_asset_asset_forms" model="ir.actions.act_window">
       <field name="name">Assets</field>
       <field name="res_model">account.asset.asset</field>
       <field name="view_type">form</field>
       <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
       <field name="view_id" ref="view_account_asset_asset_tree"/>
       <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_asset_asset_filter"/>
       <field name="domain">[('category_id.type', '=', 'purchase'), ('company_id', '=', user.company_id.id)]</field>
       <field name="context">{'search_default_draft': 1, 'search_default_open': 1, 'search_default_close': 1}</field>
       <field name="help" type="html">
                  <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                    Create assets here!
                  </p>
       </field>
   </record>
```

but I get an error. What is causing it?

Comment: what error? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You might doing wrong way...

1. domain in action should be static value or active_id.

   [('category_id.type', '=', 'purchase'), ('user_id', '=', active_id)]
2. As you want only current user realted company data to show. You should have to use "record rules"
3. Most last hackable option is override ORM method and do by code.